# Where is the Review button for users with reputation between 100 and 500?

Tags: support

How does one with reputation less than 500 access the documentation review section?

I remember seeing a 'Review' button somewhere on the Topbar and I used to review documentation changes. I don't remember when this change happened but for the last few weeks, I could not find the Review button to access the Review page.

A few days back I got my reputation to 500+. Since then I have had access to the review section via this button:

[image]

But then, part of my reputation was reversed and I went back to having less than 500; and for the life of me I could not figure out where that review button just went.

**EDIT :**
 I am surprised that it has been 22 hours and this question is still unanswered.

Comment: You lose privileges when you fall below the required reputation threshold. You seem to be back at 511 now though so you should see the button again now. Try refreshing or clearing your cache.

Comment: @BSMP I am sure I had access to Documentation reviews even before I had my reputation above 200

Comment: Just did a quick check; I had access to Documentation Review from 100 reputation

Comment: Do note that while you lose the Review link when below 500 reputation, you can still access the Documentation Reviews [directly](https://stackoverflow.com/review). I do think it is a little silly that people can participate in these reviews, but cannot easily access them.

Comment: @cteski Precisely my thoughts. On that note how do u access the Documentation review? Is a direct link visible on your homepage? I have posted this question because I am sure that I used to have a "Review" button somewhere but I can't find it now

Comment: Documentation is a bit different from the other review queues. And what's really strange is that you get access to it at 100 points. Because that means it is also accessible to people whose only rep comes from an assocation bonus. People who know literally _nothing_ about programming, can still potentially review Documentation - long as they have an assocation bonus.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I agree. But how do people with reputation between 100 and 500 access the review queue? Where is the review button?